# Default language mix up in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, language, language-pack

I added a language (in Region & Language) and then I changed the default display language to the new language. It worked. Now when I changed the display language back to "English" again, it didn't really happen for everything. I see non-English characters in start and search as shown below:

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFBOZ.png)

Restarting the system and redoing the whole process don't fix it. How can this be fixed?

Comment: Check if this happens in another user profile.

Comment: No, it does not.

Answer (score 1):

Your user profile seems to be corrupted, as the problem does not arrive
on a new profile.

You may migrate data from the old profile by using some (or all)
of the commands below :

```
copy c:\users\oldprofile\Desktop c:\users\newprofile\Desktop
copy c:\users\oldprofile\documents c:\users\newprofile\documents
copy c:\users\oldprofile\music c:\users\newprofile\music
copy c:\users\oldprofile\video c:\users\newprofile\video
copy c:\users\oldprofile\pictures c:\users\newprofile\pictures
copy c:\users\oldprofile\appdata\roaming\microsoft\outlook c:\users\newprofile\appdata\roaming\microsoft\outlook
```

For Start Menu settings, copy
`C:\Users\oldprofile\AppData\Local\TileDataLayer\Database`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you also try changing the system locale? Try the following, if that fails, perhaps try a system restore to a point before you made changes (if the checkpoint is available):

1. In search tab type "Region" and press enter.
2. In new window select "Administrative"
3. then click on "change system locale"
4. Select the language.

Comment: It's already English. So that doesn't resolve the issue