# Windows 10 locale stuck in German

Tags: windows-10, language

I have a Thinkpad that runs Windows 10 Pro including the latest software updates - but it's in German. I have tried many times to change the system language to US English, but there is always some remnant of German here and there, not least in the Start menu and the boot+login screens. It is infuriating and frustrating because Windows 10 makes everything "look nice" at the cost of being intransparent to configure.

I have even tried a complete machine reset using Windows10's built-in restore functionality, in the hope that the first choice in that process would be to set the system language. But there was no such choice.

I have seen numerous answers [like this one](https://superuser.com/a/1250999/9350) which helped change the boot&login language. But e.g. headings in the Start menu are still in German.

What I've tried: *all of the following* is set to US English:

- Settings > Time & language > Region > Region
- Settings > Time & language > Region > Regional format
- Settings > Time & language > Language > Windows display language
- Settings > Time & language > Language > Preferred languages
- Settings > Time & language > Speech > Speech language

Anything German has been *removed* except that in *Settings > Time & language > Language > Windows display language* the drop-down menu contains English(US) and German -- how can I completely remove German from this list? Also, *Settings > Time & language > Speech > Installed voice packages* still contains German (and US English) and the "remove" button is disabled.

Despite all of the above, applications still think the machine is in German and display their menus in German. Surely there must be a way to **get rid of German *entirely*?**

Comment: [How to Change the Language of Welcome Screen in Windows 10](https://blog.techinline.com/2016/03/29/how-to-change-the-language-of-welcome-screen-in-windows-10/)

Comment: Thanks @DavidPostill I just made an edit that reflects this too. It's still not all the way gone though.

Comment: What comes back when you run `Get-WinSystemLocale`, and `Get-Culture` via powershell?

Comment: @spikey_richie / they both return `1033   en-US   English (United States)`.

Comment: `Get-WinHomeLocation` ?

Comment: Have you checked what `bcdedit` gives you? The locale can also be set there.

Comment: `Get-WinHomeLocation` gives me `244 United States`. And `bcdedit` tells me that locale is `en-US`. -- All of these command suggestions are completely new to me, by the way, so thank you! It looks like everything is set correctly so far, "and yet..."